# Boldy theme  - Regarding the images above the boxes

Tags: themes, images

Hello I am using the Boldy theme for my Wordpress website. I have a problem with the boxes (all 3 of them). All these three boxes have a "read more" that takes the user to another page, and above these boxes there is a small image.

Now I want the images for each box to take the user to another page as well, but how can you make each image to turn them into a link in wordpress?

Here is my home.php this might help.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- BEGIN SLIDER -->

      <div id="slider">

            <?php if(get_option('boldy_slider')!=''){

            $page_data = get_page(get_option('boldy_slider'));

                    $content = $page_data->post_content;

                    echo $page_data->post_content;

            }else{?>

                <div style="border:1px solid #ddd; text-align:center; padding:150px 100px 0; height:219px; font-size:14px;">

                    This is the slider. In order to have items here you need to create a page in which to insert the images, simply one after another, setting up the link to point at ( if needed ) and text captions in the Title field. Then select the page as the "slider page" in the Theme Options Page. Make sure your images are 960px x 370px.

                </div>

            <?php }?>

        </div>

       <div style="width:960px; margin:0 auto; background:url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bk_shadow_slider.png) 0 0 no-repeat; height:50px;"></div>

       <!-- END SLIDER -->

       <!-- BEGIN BLURB -->

       <?php if(get_option('boldy_blurb_enable')=="yes" && get_option('boldy_blurb_text')!=""){ ?>

       <div id="blurb">

            <p>

            <a href="<?php 

            if(get_option('boldy_blurb_page')!=""){

                echo get_permalink(get_option('boldy_blurb_page'));

            }elseif(get_option('boldy_blurb_link')!=""){

                echo get_option('boldy_blurb_link');

            } ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/but_blurb.png" alt="" /></a>

            <?php echo get_option('boldy_blurb_text'); ?> 

            </p>

       </div>

       <?php }?>

       <!-- END BLURB -->

       <!-- BEGIN HOME CONTENT -->

       <!-- begin home boxes -->

        <?php $box1=get_post(get_option('boldy_home_box1'));

                  $box2=get_post(get_option('boldy_home_box2'));

                  $box3=get_post(get_option('boldy_home_box3')); 

                  if(get_option('boldy_home_box1')!= null && get_option('boldy_home_box2')!= null && get_option('boldy_home_box3')!= null){?>

        <div id="homeBoxes" class="clearfix">

            <div class="homeBox">

                <h2><?php echo $box1->post_title?></h2>

                <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $box1->post_content);?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_option('boldy_home_box1_link')?>"><strong>Read more &raquo;</strong></a>

            </div>

            <div class="homeBox">

                <h2><?php echo $box2->post_title?></h2>

                <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $box2->post_content);?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_option('boldy_home_box2_link')?>"><strong>Read more &raquo;</strong></a>

            </div>

            <div class="homeBox last">

                <h2><?php echo $box3->post_title?></h2>

                <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $box3->post_content);?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_option('boldy_home_box3_link')?>"><strong>Read more &raquo;</strong></a>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Did you create a page/post for each of these images?

Comment: @ Stephen Harris:  I create a page for all three images - so yes.

Comment: @ Stephen Harris: Oh I see. go to pages, edit the pages you want to edit. Then select your image and go to insert/edit link and assign a url. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are produced by simply displaying the content of the pages you created for each, box.

Go to each of theses pages, click the image. On the top-left corner of the image two icons should appear. Click the edit icon (the leftmost icon).

A dialog window will pop-up, which will allow you to edit the properties of the image (title, caption etc). Among this is 'link url' - change this to wherever you would like the image to link to. Click update. And then finally update the page.